# Regex for credit card expiration

Tags: regex, validation, credit-card

I'm trying to write an expression that will validate a credit card expiration in the form of MM / YY. The original expression I came up with is:

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\d{2}$/
```

This works fine except it doesn't account for the spaces on either side of the /. How can I modify it?

Thanks

Comment: `/^\d{1,2}\s*\/\s*\d{2}$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using following regular expression:

```
/^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) *\/ *[1-9][0-9]$/
```

The month must be with the OR expression in a non marking group

- either a single digit number in range `1` to `9` and therefore `0` is not valid,
- or a two digit number with first digit being `0` and second digit being `1` to `9` and therefore `00` is not valid,
- or a two digit number being `10` or `11` or `12`.

The year must be a two digit number with first digit being not `0` as this is impossible for an expiration date up to year 2100.

0 or more spaces are allowed around `/`, but no other whitespace characters like carriage return, line-feed, horizontal tab, vertical tab, etc. all matched by `\s`.